# What's the difference between different type of pointers?

Tags: pointers, go

A pointer references a location in memory. Actually all memory addresses have the same type independently of the variable type as far as I understand.

Instead of using different pointer type (`*int`, `*string` etc..), is this possible using only one type (`var p pointer`) for all the pointer types?

What is the difference between different pointer types?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 5
    s := "abc"

    var pi *int      // alternatively var pi pointer
    var ps *string   // alternatively var ps pointer 

    pi = &i
    ps = &s

    fmt.Printf("%p %p", pi, ps)  // result is 0x1040e0f8 0x1040a120
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this possible using only one type for all the pointer types?

Yes, that is pretty much how C works. Unfortunately, that makes the language dangerous. Say you have an array of 10 bytes. If you JUST pass the pointer, the other code won't know how many bytes it's safe to access. That leads to all kinds of buffer overflow errors. (i.e. HeartBleed)

In Go, they pointer knows the type of the thing it points to, so it can prevent your code from having buffer overflow problems all the time.

You can do what you want, but only by using the Unsafe package. As the name suggests, that is a very dangerous thing to do.

Perhaps if you post what you are ACTUALLY trying to do, people can help you. Using unsafe pointers is not the only way to write performant code.

Comment: When was the last time you programmed in C? 1970? C pointers have the type of "pointer to the thing they are pointing to". They are not all one type.

Comment: Try this experiment: `int a=42; int p=&a; p=43`. Yes, that code is logically wrong, but the default compiler won't stop you from *writing and running* that code. Even worse, a novice can use a cast to 'fix' the problem, hiding it forever. C may have "different pointer types", but without enforcement it can't prevent bugs. In contrast, Go won't compile code like that, and will reject any attempts to 'fix' the problem with a cast. And we can scare away any novices from using the "unsafe" module because it's almost never needed.

Answer (score 2):

The type system in Go is designed to prevent memory errors relating to pointers. This allows programmers to have enough control to manipulate objects in memory while Allowing the garbage collector top cop moody of the heavy lifting.
If you need to manually memory and convert pointer types you can use the [unsafe package](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe).

Comment: Thank you for reply. But this explanation is far away to me due to my lack of information. A pointer is referance to memory that is represented as an 32 bit or 64 bit int. Is this correct ?. If this information is correct, why are we use different pointer types related to variable type? If this information is not correct, what is the differance between different pointer types?

Comment: @AliAltun first of all, one key point is that if all pointers were the same, you'd lose type information and make the language much less efficient and less safe. You wouldn't want a function accepting `*int` to accept `*float`, or you're losing one of the key advantages of a statically typed langues.